# Save as UTF-8 Error?

Tags: android, eclipse, encoding

I am using eclipse juno and android 2.3 Ginger bread.I create a project and did edit.When I try to save the file it shows the error message.It shows as a message box

```
Save could not be completed. Try file > save as ... if problem persists.
Reason:
some characters cannot be maped using " Cp1252 " character encoding.
Either chande the encounting or remove the characters which are not
supported by the " Cp1252 " character ebcoding.
```

It has 3 options

1. OK
2. Save as UTF-8
3. select first character

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Save your source files as UTF-8. Right click on project, select properties and change content encoding. Note: this will only work for newly created files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use special characters in you java files. put strings in strings.xml (which is always in UTF-8, so no problem here)

Comment: cp1252 is the default encoding in Windows. It is therefore used by default be eclipse. You can change the workspace-wide encoding settings in Eclipse preferences

Comment: hello you know what is FATAL exception ........ i searched but i didn't get ..is this fatal exception is related with encoding....When I run the project I got fatal exception

Comment: probably related to encoding inside your code. create a new question with relevant code and stacktrace